# Select one value from multiple same dates

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have 2 tables in table1 I have id, datetime and power in table2 I have id_connection(connection to table1), datetime_imported (when was this value imported)

table1:

```
id  datetime    power
1   2020-07-01  2.1
2   2020-07-01  0
3   2020-07-01  2.5
4   2020-07-02  1.6
5   2020-07-02  1.1
6   2020-07-02  0
```

table2:

```
id_connection datime_imported
1             2020-08-01
2             2020-08-02
3             2020-08-03
4             2020-08-04
5             2020-08-05
6             2020-08-06
```

So I want to get 1 value(power) per datetime and that datetime have to be lastest imported. So the result should look

result:

```
datetime   power
2020-07-01 2.5
2020-07-02 0
```

Comment: Use `distinct on ()`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group+postgresql

Comment: Your requirement is not clear. Latest imported date is `2020-08-06`, but you want to get result from `2020-07-01` and '2020-07-02'.

Comment: What is the role of table2 with respect to the output ?

Comment: I'm lost.  Do your "datetime" columns have time components?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT table2.datime_imported, table1.power
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.id = table2.id_connection;
```

This assumes that both the imported date in `table2` and `power` from `table1` are overwritten when updated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether it matches your problem or not but hope this helps.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (datetime)
    id, 
    datetime,
    power,
    datetime_imported
FROM table1 A
INNER JOIN table2 B
ON A.id = B.id_connection
ORDER BY datetime ASC, datetime_imported DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT on (a.datetime) * 
FROM A a, B b 
WHERE a.id=b.id_connection 
ORDER BY a.datetime ,a.id DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH a AS (
  SELECT
    t1.datetime,t1.power,
    row_number() over(partition BY a,datetime ORDER BY a.power DESC) rnk
  FROM TABLE_1 t1
  LEFT JOIN TABLE_2 t2
  ON t1.id = t2.id_connection
)
SELECT * FROM a WHERE a.rnk = 1;
```

Comment: Please refrain from answering with code-only. Note that you are not only answering to the OP, but also to any future readers of the question. Thus, please edit the post to contain an explanation as to why this line of code works.